# Redirect ggplot2 prints to a singple pdf file inside parLapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, doparallel

I would like to know if there is a way to get a single PDF file containing all the plots that are generated inside `parLapply`. I tried by using `outfile` option in the `makeClusters` function, but it gave me a PDF that I could not open.

Regards,

Juan